# Codeigniter like wildcard

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

When I want to write following line in Codeigniter:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE City LIKE '%es%'; // CONTAINS 'es'
```

I write this code:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('Customers');
$this->db->like('City', 'es');
```

Could you please help me to write relevant code for the following line:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE City LIKE 'ber%'; // STARTS WITH 'ber'
```

So that it will show information for cities which start with 'ber'

Comment: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html  `If you want to control where the wildcard (%) is placed, you can use an optional third argument. Your options are 'before', 'after' and 'both' (which is the default).` and then `$this->db->like('title', 'match', 'after'); 
// Produces: WHERE title LIKE 'match%' `

Comment: Useguide's now can be found here CI3 http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-similar-data CI2 http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a third parameter to define where the wildcard will go:

```
$this->db->like('City', 'es', 'after');
//SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE City LIKE 'ber%'

$this->db->like('City', 'es', 'before');
//SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE City LIKE '%ber'

$this->db->like('City', 'es', 'both'); //Default
//SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE City LIKE '%ber%'
```

Comment: No problem. Glad to help :)